# Is it realistic for a postdoc to negotiate for a private office?

Tags: postdocs, negotiation

If a postdoc requests a private office when negotiating an employment contract, is there a possibility the request would be granted?

Comment: Anything can happen during negotiations.

Comment: Stranger things have happened.

Comment: What if one new postdoc gets a private office, but the others all share 3 or 4 to an office...  Will that cause friction among them?

Comment: @GEdgar: Yes, probably.  Thus my guess is that this will not be negotiable.  On the other hand, it still might be useful to ask whether you will have a private office; that could be something to consider when weighing competing offers.

Comment: Please let us know the outcome of the office space negotiation. It will be a useful data point for future postdocs.

Comment: Yes. We have enough space to grant such a request and I assume some other institutions are in a similar fortunate situation. Many others are not. Your question is not specific enough.

Comment: Be prepared to explain why you need it.

Comment: I've seen undergrads with private offices and labs.

Comment: The best offices are not one-person offices but two-person offices. There is someone to have a conversation with if you want to, but if you don't want to have a conversation no one else will be speaking.

Comment: @jwg This depends on your personality. I vastly prefer a one-person room. Also, if you have a two-person office, but you don't really like the other person, it's about the worst.

Comment: What I want to know is why all the financial admin in my building, who do no research, all have their own giant offices when post-docs and even some professors do not. Sure, they play an important and vital role for us but surely they could share an office like the rest of us?

Comment: If this is in the US: Do you need a window?

Comment: Just ask. The worst thing they can do is say no. It all depends on availability of space. I've personally had a private office as a PhD student, and I've known Professors with a shared office.

Answer (score 35):

The big issue in having a private office is available space.

Most departments have a limited amount of space available, and what is given to any particular research group is correspondingly restricted. There may not be a private office available to the group, in which case it wouldn't be possible to accommodate such a request. In addition, if there's a more senior person, then usually such an individual would have a "higher claim," so you might not get one.

Of course, if you never ask, you'll never know.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does negotiation work in academic settings? Is it like "Hey, can I get a private office?" "Yes" (or) "No". I don't see how exactly one could negotiate...

Comment: Yeah, it's not really a negotiation—you just ask.

Comment: "Yes", "No", or in one case the departmental secretary's thousand-yard-office-politics-stare and "Don't even ask."

Comment: @gokul_uf it works just like in any other setting. You apply for jobs, get X job offers, and if X>1, you are in a pretty good position to negotiate the terms with each of the places making you an offer, and then select the job that appeals to you most.

Answer (score 20):

Sure there is a possibility. I have seen PhD students have private offices in some places. In others, even Assistant Professors had to share. And my current employer famously had a (short-lived) initiative where they wanted to implement a hot-seat scheme for everybody except top administrators (it did not go over well with faculty).

However, in practice you may not so much negotiate but ask for it. If they have the room they will be happy to oblige (since it costs them little), and if they don't have the room they will hardly be able to change this to accommodate your request. Further, note that room situations change, sometimes quite quickly - you may have a comfy single office when you start, and a few successful grant applications later you need to share the same space with two others. It is unlikely that your PI will guarantee you in writing that you will have and retain a single office at all times.

One of the comments also asks whether there will be "friction" if you have a single office and others on your level need to share. This is of course possible, and it depends a bit on your personality whether you would mind this (I personally wouldn't). However, there's usually advantages and disadvantages to all rooms. Your single office will likely be of the "small dark room in the corner" variety, while their three-person office is surely larger, and often nicer - so it's not a straight up "you got a much better deal than others". Further, if you always worry that others might be envious of whatever you manage to negotiate on top of the standard package, then why bother negotiating at all?

Comment: My title is Senior Lecturer, and I am sharing an office with 3 Senior and 1 Principal Lecturer.

Answer (score 3):

If a private office is important to you, there's no better time to ask than at recruitment / when you have an offer letter in hand and have not yet accepted.  On the other hand, be prepared to accept a "no" answer.
On the gripping hand, the answer is always "no" to a question you haven't asked.